# How to accept any key in jsonb path?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, jsonpath, json-path-expression

I have a `jsonb` saved in a PostgreSQL database that has the structure:

```json
{
  "foo": {
    "key0": {
      "bar": "myValueA",
    },
    "key1": {
      "bar": "myValueB",
    }
    // ...
    "keyN": {
      "bar": "myValueN",
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to get all the records that have the text `"myValueX"` among all the paths `'foo' > ANY_KEY > 'bar'`

It could be `'foo' > 'key0' > 'bar'` or `'foo' > 'key1' > 'bar'` or any `keyN`.

In *"pseudo"* PostgreSQL:

```sql
SELECT * FROM "myTable" WHERE "myColumn" #>> '{foo,*,bar}' = 'myValue';
```

where `*` would mean *"can be any key"*.

Is there a way to achieve such a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not *pseudo PostgreSQL*, it's just PostgreSQL [JSONPath](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH). The [`@@` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) works exactly like that: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/zcDC05Eb)

```
select * from "myTable" 
where "myColumn" @@ '$.foo.*.bar=="myValueN"';
```

| myColumn |
| --- |
| {"foo": {"key0": {"bar": "myValueA"}, "key1": {"bar": "myValueB"}, "keyN": {"bar": "myValueN"}}} |

`@@` is [supported by GIN `jsonb_ops` and `jsonb_path_ops`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING), so you can speed it up with an index:

```sql
create index on "myTable" using gin("myColumn");
```

Comment: [Supported since version 12.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/12.0/)